# Pow config.ru for serving static files outside of the public directory?

Tags: rack, rack-pow

How do you setup a config.ru file to have Pow serve html/css/js files outside of the public directory? Let's say I wanted to serve them out of the html folder instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`TryStatic`](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/blob/master/lib/rack/contrib/try_static.rb) from [rack-contrib](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib):

```ruby
require 'rack/contrib/try_static'

use Rack::TryStatic,
  :root => "html",
  :urls => %w[/]
```

You might want to add `if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'` if you only want this during development (e.g. if your web server is configured to serve from `html/`)
.

Comment: Installed rack-contrib via gem. But kept getting this error with those settings in the config.ru.  NameError: uninitialized constant Rack::TryStatic

Comment: It looks like `TryStatic` isn't autoloaded in the `rack/contrib.rb`, try `require 'rack/contrib/try_static'` instead; see my updated answer.

Comment: After making that change I'm getting this error.
AssertionError: Status must be >= 100
    at ClientResponse._receiveData (/Users/david/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/lib/client.js:257:27)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/david/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/lib/client.js:47:33)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/david/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/node_modules/netstring/lib/ns.js:206:16)
    at Client.emit (events.js:64:17)